# design pattern to express that "container" over derived class is derived from container of a base class

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, containers

I have a class `Track` which holds a set of `Point`s and represent person location in time. In order to get this result I run an iterative optimization routine combining different data. In order to do it I extend `Point` with a class `OptimizedPoint` which holds data for optimization for this point and current value. I also introduce OptimizedTrack which is a collection of `OptimizedPoints` and additional data needed for optimization associated with the whole track.

I run an optimization on `OptimizedTrack` and at the last iteration, I return to the user clean data (`Track`) which only has the result and doesn't have additional data. However, I can not find a way to express with OOP that `OptimizedTrack` is somehow an extension of the `Track` and introduce common routines for them. F.e getting a length of the track which should be available for both of them as it only uses data which can be found both in `OptimizedTrack` and `Track`

Right now I have such architecture `Point{x, y, z}, OptimizedPoint extends Point {additional_data}. Track {array<Point>}, OptimizedTrack {array<OptimizedPoint>, additional_data}`. I don't understand how to express that `OptimizedTrack` is an extension of Track as I can not express `array<OptimizedPoint>` extens `array<Point>`. So I can not introduce a common routine `length` which can be calculated for array and therefore also from array.

I do not insist on my current architecture. It's most probably wrong, I only write it here to express the problem I am facing. How would you propose to refactor my architecture in this case?

Comment: Why do you want to extend Track? If the optimization is done and then you dont need the temporary data anymore, you can define `optimize()` as a method of `Track`. If you want to keep the additional data, you may create a `class TrackOptimizer` that has a `Track` instance as a member (composition over inheritance) and a method `optimize()` that return a clean `Track`.

Comment: @Lini `Track` contains `Point`s. For optimization I need to store `OptimizedPoint`s. in `OptimizedTrack`

Comment: I know you want ot store `OptimizedPoint`s in a collection. Does it have to be a new class `OptimizedTrack`  which extends `Track`? Do you return to user a `Track` or a `OptimizedTrack`?

Comment: @lini It doesn't have to be an extension; I am asking for possible architectures for my task. I want to return `Track` to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the basic premise of what you are trying to do is faulty *if you are following what is considered to be proper use of inheritance to express subtyping relationships.*

Inheritance can be used for various purposes and I am not wishing to pontificate upon the subject, but the opinion of most authorities is that inheritance is best and most safely used when used for subtyping. In short, an instance of a subclass should be able to be substituted for an instance of its base class without "breaking" the program (see: Liskov Substitution Principle).

Let us assume that `OptimizedPoint` is a subtype of `Point`. Then all the methods defined in class `Point` when invoked on an instance of `OptimizedPoint` will continue to function as expected. That means that `OptimizedPoint` cannot require any more stringent preconditions on any of these method invocations nor can it weaken any of the promissed postconditions that the contract `Point` has made.

But it is a common fallacy that just becuase `OptimizedPoint` is a subtype of `Point` that a container of `OptimizedPoint`, i.e. `OptimizedTrack`, is a subtype of a container of `Point`, i.e `Track`. This is because you cannot substitute an instance of `OptimizedTrack` for an instance of `Track` (due to your not being able to add an instance of `Point` to an instance of `OptimizedTrack`).

**So, if you are trying to follow "good object-oriented design principles", it is disastrous trying to somehow make `OptimizedTrack` a subclass of `Track`, because it can certainly never be a subtype. You can, of course, reuse `Track` to build `OptimizedTrack` using composition, i.e. `OptimizedTrack` would contain within an instance of `Track` to which methods such as `length` would be delegated.**

Comment: thank you for the answer. How would you change the architecture if you wanted to have an observer on a different thread to Track (and also OptimizedTrack)

Comment: Again, the reason why `OptimizedTrack` cannot be a subtype of `Track` is because `Track` will have a method such as `add(Point)` (I am trying not to make this too language-specific) and this method makes no sense for an `OptimizedTrack`. But you can defined a new interface called, for example, `PointContainer`, which defines methods for accessing its `Point` members but does not provide the ability for adding new points. Both `OptimizedTrack` and `Track` classes can implement this class! So, you provide an observer on `PointContainer`. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to return a `Track` to your client code after the optimisation process, considering that `OptimizedTrack` is a `Track` itself.  Below is a quick example of what I think you're trying to achieve (written in Kotlin because is less verbose).

You can achieve a lot more flexibility and solve the type issue if you consider `Track` to be an iterable object of points of type `Point`. This way, when you extend `OptTrack` from `Track`, you will be able to:

1. Substitute `Track` and `OptTrack` with no problem (even if your optimised track object has not computed a simplified `Track` object).
2. Simplify through `optimize` and return a `Track` from `OptTrack` with no issues (the `optimize` function on `Point` is irrelevant, you can return an `OptPoint` inside your `Track` because it extends the object `Point`)

```kotlin
    open class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int) {
        override fun toString(): String = 
            "Point(${this.x}, ${this.y}, ${this.z})"
    }

    data class OptPoint(val point: Point, val additional: Int): 
        Point(point.x, point.y, point.z) {
        
        override fun toString(): String = 
            "OptPoint(${this.point}, ${this.additional})"
            
        fun optimize(): Point {
            return Point(this.x, this.y, this.z)
        }
    }

    open class Track(private val points: Iterable<Point>): Iterable<Point> {
        
        override operator fun iterator(): Iterator<Point> {
            return this.points.iterator()
        }
        
        override fun toString(): String = 
            "Track(${this.points})"
    }

    data class OptTrack(private val points: Iterable<OptPoint>): Track(listOf()) {
        
        override operator fun iterator(): Iterator<Point> {
            return this.points.iterator()
        }
        
        fun optimize(): Track {
            return Track(this.points.map{ it.optimize() })
        }
    }

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val track: Track = OptTrack(listOf(
                 OptPoint(Point(1, 2, 3), 4))).optimize()
        println(track)        
        // Track([Point(1, 2, 3)])
        val other: Track = OptTrack(listOf(OptPoint(Point(1, 2, 3), 4)))
        println(other)
        // OptTrack(points=[OptPoint(Point(1, 2, 3), 4)])
    }
```

Comment: "I'm not sure why you want to return a Track to your client code after the optimisation process" - I don't want the user to know about the optimization internals

Comment: Well, then this approach ^ should solve that. Note that you can take this one step forward and encapsulate the optimisation computation in a strategy object, and then compose the strategy object with `Track` (to eliminate the need for `OptTrack`), or compose it with `OptTrack` for more flexibility in the future. In short, you don't need an `optimize()` function - you can encapsulate the whole in objects and lazy computations.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP you should prefer object composition to object inheritance. In your problem, I think creating interfaces for point and track could help. In order to achieve the proper result, I think, you should create two interfaces, IPoint & ITrack. Both Track and OptimizedTrack implement the ITrack interface and for common operations, you could create another class that both classes delegate the requests to it. After that you could create an strategy class, taking in an ITrack and returns another optimized ITrack. In the ITrack you could create GetPath which returns a list of objects of type IPoint.